# Last call duration in objective c?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, calllog

I'm doing enterprise application. I need to detect last call duration from my application. I gone through `core telephony framework` but it will work only upto iOS 4.0. Can you please give me proper guidance to solve my problem.

Thanking you

Answer (score 2):

Unfortunately you can't access the call history. The only User Data you have API access to is the address book. You can also access photos/pictures but only by starting an iPhone-controlled dialog that allows the user to choose a single image.

**Note :**-A **CTCarrier** object gives you information about the user’s cellular service provider, such as whether it allows use of VoIP (Voice over Internet Protocol) on its network. A CTCall object gives you information about a current call, including a unique identifier and state information—dialing, incoming, connected, or disconnected.

[Read Link :-](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/NetworkingInternet/Reference/CoreTelephonyFrameworkReference/_index.html)

Comment: So I can get the Current call information (duration)using 'CTCarrier'?

Comment: if your application is use VoIP features then you use Call history otherwise its not possible